# How to change format of Datetime variable in einstein chatbot Salesforce?

Tags: datetime, salesforce, chatbot, salesforce-einstein

In Einstein Bot as I see, after client answers an question about datetime, salesforce will display our datetime with MM/DD/YYYY format.
I want to change that format to DD/MM/YYYY.
Can we customize this ?